# IPアドレスから住所を検索するサイトの検索結果が変わるのはなぜか？

Tags: network, security

セキュリティについて勉強しているものです。

最近、IPアドレスで自分をトラックしつつ働きを確認しているのですが
IPアドレスから大体の住所を検索するサイトで検索すると

## 質問1

サイトによって大きく異なる住所が返されます。これはどうしてでしょうか？

- https://ipinfo.io/
- https://db-ip.com/all/
- https://www.iphiroba.jp

## 質問2

IPアドレスだけで住所を詳細に特定できない理由はどうしてでしょうか？

## 質問3

他にどんな情報があればより正確に、例えば市町村規模で特定できるのでしょうか？

- ISP
- Host Name

などは有効なのでしょうか？理由もお聞かせ願いたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、質問2からですが…そもそもIPアドレス自体が現実世界の「住所」と紐づいて管理されていないので正確な情報なんて出てくるわけがありません。
そのうえで、ISPのふりわける傾向に従って、地域を大まかに特定しているのだと思われます。

なので、正確に「住所」をしるためには「GPS」などの位置情報から割り出す必要があります。

Comment: 質問１についてはどうしてでしょうか？

Comment: 上記の回答で自明だと思ったのですが、点で返さないといけませんね。
各サイトで「住所を類推する方法」が異なるからだと考えられます。
標準化された仕様がない以上異なるのは当たり前です。いってみれば「俺の生年月日の占い結果がサイトごとに違うけどなんで？」という話と同レベルかと。。

Comment: なるほど、異なるからだと考えられます、ということですがここをもう少し詳しく、つまり、具体的にどういった異なる方法が用いられてるか知りたいのですがどう調べればいいでしょうか？

Comment: それは当該業者のノウハウに相当するので、業者がその方法を公開していればよし、公開してなきゃ門外不出の秘伝みたいなもので簡単に調べることはできないでしょう。

Comment: なるほど、IPから場所を調べるシステム？のようなものを調べてみることにします